# Get Updated Contacts in Android for Contact Sync

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, contacts

I am working on Contact Sync in Android and I have successfully done with First time Contact Sync.

Here is what I am doing.
 1. Fetching all Contacts and Saving each contact in DB with Contact._ID
 2. Fetching Names and Phone Numbers and saving in DB.

After that I am sending my contacts data to server so that server can be updated.

Now the problem is how can i check whether my particular contact is updated or not ?

I have implemented Broadcast Receiver so that my app can get intimated about the updation/Addition/Deletion of Contact. But I want to tract particular contact.

I found one solution which is Dirty Flag. It tells us about the contact whether its updated or not, Here is the reference link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html

But I am not able to use this Dirty Flag, Could someone please help me by implementing Dirty Flag.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: why aren't you able to use it?

Comment: Have you got the solution?  I am facing the same problem in my application

Answer (score 5):

The contacts should have the value `ContactsContract.RawContacts.VERSION`.

If you save this version on the server (or in a database in your app), you can determine if a contact has changed since it was last sent to the server.

Comment: any comments on this ? I am still looking for perfect solution.

Comment: No, sorry. I'd have to try it out myself, but I currently don't have the time for that.

Answer (score 4):

You will get number of contacts updated after a particular time from contact data base using below query.

```
 ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP
```

,try to compare the last uploaded time to your server with this time .Hope then you will get the list of updated contacts after the successful upload to server.

check this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP

Comment: you can use sqlite database to store the contact with some time stamp.and you can make some kind of comparison and update the table ..try this way

Comment: It had a problem, whenever you make any calls and do not modify any fields in the contact, android automatically update the value of CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP to the time of call, which is wrong

Comment: It alo depends on system time, so whenever you change date and time of your device it will also affect the value of  CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Any luck? I am trying to sync contacts for the past 3 months and really need some help. Using CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP is NOT good. For some very strange reason, android updates contacts timestamp for no reason! last time i even called these contacts was couple of years ago. Please advise. #AndroidIsTheWorst

Answer (score 3):

When I did I used the ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP, but I had problem to figure out that it was is milliseconds, I was using a column to get the new files and it is in seconds (MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED) so pay attention to use the correct number.

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
Cursor cursorNew;
cursorNew = contentResolver.query(uri,
        null,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP + ">=?",
        new String[]{lastUpdate},
        null        // Ordering
);
```

'lastUpdate' is a string with my timestamp

Another thing to pay attention is this Contact's column just appeared on API 18, the latest Jelly Bean version, so to solve this problem once and for all I just changed my gradle file.

Comment: What's about the answer that CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP is updated on each call? How had you worked on this?

Comment: Share Gaket question. CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP changes in many other unknown reasons.

Answer (score 2):

As you said that you are storing `Contacts._ID` in your local database and fetching `phone number` and other info associated with contact from the `Contacts` db.

I would suggest you to store the data from the `RawContacts` table into your local mapping and check the entries associated with the `raw_contact_id` in the `data` table of contacts you will get all contacts easily.

To check the modified or deleted contacts
With the `raw_contact_id` present in your local table check mapping with the `data` table that if contact field associated with the `raw_contact_id's` `version` is changed or `isDeleted` field is changed (i.e; Contact is deleted from contact application)

Comment: can you please provide example?